# Special usage of " | " operator, like catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e)

Tags: java, casting, boolean, identifier, bitwise-or

I got this idea because of eclipse (Java) where it showed the possibillity to add multiple exceptions to a catch clause like this:

```
String someInput;
int int1;

try {
    int1 = Integer.parseInt(someInput);
} catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
}
```

So does that mean that i can also do stuff like that?:

```
boolen bool1 = (int1 == (int2 | int3));
```

or cast an object like this?:

```
(obj1 | obj2) someObject;
```

or allways specify Objects like this?:

```
obj1 | obj2 someName;
```

thank you for any answers,
Ayren

Comment: What programming language are you refering to?

Comment: You can just try to run this code and see if it works

Comment: It depends on the programming language. It's not C++ and it doesn't look like Java or C#. What is it?

Comment: @iTayb added the language as tag

Comment: easy to verify say int1 = 3 ; int2 = 1 and int3 = 2 ; you then have int1 == (int2 | int3) (because 1 or 2 = 3) but int1 wasn't equal to int2 or int3

Comment: The use of the vertical bar for catch blocks is not a bitwise or. It is a construct specific to catch blocks that allows multiple exception types to be specified called alternatives. It does not generalize to other places in the language.

Comment: The new Java Multi-Catch feature is BTW described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: I think it is a good question - two different uses of | in Java can be a source of bafflement. And it will be not the first one in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `|` in an exception catch phrase is not as an operator.  It is a special syntax that allows you to catch a set of exceptions.

> So does that mean that i can also do stuff like that?:
>
> ```
>    boolean bool1 = (int1 == (int2 | int3));
> ```
>
> or cast an object like this?:
>
> ```
>    (obj1 | obj2) someObject;
> ```
>
> or always specify Objects like this?:
>
> ```
>    obj1 | obj2 someName;
> ```

No, no and no.

That special syntax can *only* be used in the specific context of a catch phrase "signature".

Note that your first example is syntactically correct, but it does not do what you think.  Specifically, these two statements mean different things:

```
boolean bool1 = (int1 == (int2 | int3));
boolean bool2 = ((int1 == int2) || (int == int3));
```

The first one performs a bitwise OR of `int2` and `int3` and tests if the result is equal to `int1`.  If we try this with `int1 == 0b0011`, `int2 == 0b0001` and `int3 == 0b0010`, `bool1` will be `true` and `bool2` will be `false`.

The other two examples are syntactically incorrect (as expressions).

Answer (score 2):

- `||` is a logical operator and can **only** be applied to `boolean` values.
- `|` is a bitwise operator and can be applied to **integer** types as well.

Bitwise operators perform operations on each bit of the **integer** number. For example: `5 | 6 = 7` (`00000101 | 00000110 = 00000111`). It is commonly used to add and compare flags set on different bits of an integer number (instead of array of booleans).

In case of **exceptions**, this construction came with Java 7. You may now catch several exception types with a single `catch` statement. The vertical bar in this case is not an operator, but rather an element of the new construction.

You cannot, however, use `|` (nor `||`) as operators with objects.

Answer (score 0):

At least in C++, the two statements are not equivalent:

statement1 : `(int1 == int2 || int1 == int3)`

statement2:  `( int1 == (int2 | int3) )`

The operator | is a bitwise OR. That is, `(00001111 | 11110000)` will result in `11111111`.

Let's say `int1` in binary is `1111`, while `int2` is `1100` and `int3` is `0011`.
Then statement1 will return `false`, while statement2 will return `true`.

Comment: | is a logical operator as well. Its the non short circuit version of || which means even if the first condition is true the second one will be evaluated.